# Passing Multiple arguments to jQuery Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have a function which gets the data from various input ( multiple values ) and populate into a table.

Here is the jquery snippet :

```
var row =1   
$("input[name='product_id[]']").each(function() {               
        $rows[row].cells[0].innerText = $(this).val();      
        row = row+1;
    });

    row=1;
    $("input[name='product_name[]']").each(function() {             
        $rows[row].cells[1].innerText = $(this).val();      
        row = row+1;
    });

    row=1;
    $("input[name='manufacturer[]']").each(function() {             
        $rows[row].cells[2].innerText = $(this).val();      
        row = row+1;
    });

    row=1;
    $("input[name='composition[]']").each(function() {              
        $rows[row].cells[3].innerText = $(this).val();      
        row = row+1;
    });
```

I was wondering if I can combine multiple iterators into a single iterator ?

Thanks
Kiran

Answer (score 4):

Create a common function, this will help your **row logic**, **which gets value 1 before each iteration**

```
function iteratorOperation(){
}
```

And then pass this to the iterators,

```
$("input[name='product_id[]']").each(iteratorOperation);

row=1;
$("input[name='product_name[]']").each(iteratorOperation);

row=1;
$("input[name='manufacturer[]']").each(iteratorOperation);

row=1;
$("input[name='composition[]']").each(iteratorOperation);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can join the selectors by commas:

```
$("input[name='product_id[]'], input[name='product_name[]'], input[name='manufacturer[]'], input[name='composition[]']")
.each(function() {
  // ...
});
```

To be more DRY, use an array:

```
const selectorStr = ['product_id', 'product_name', 'manufacturer', 'composition']
  .map(str => `input[name='${str}[]']`)
  .join(',');
$(selectorStr).each(function() {
  // ...
});
```

If you need `row` to be `1` in all but the first iteration, then:

```
['product_id', 'product_name', 'manufacturer', 'composition']
  .forEach((str, i) => {
    if (i !== 0) {
      row = 1;
    }
    $(`input[name='${str}[]']`).each(function(){
      // etc
    });
  });
```

Comment: Good one. But the variable row value will differ. It should be initialized to 1, before each separate iteration starts, as he added in question. In your case the common row value will be shared in all iterations

Comment: OP didn't describe his use of `rows` or show how / if it's relevant to the iterations, but if needed, use `forEach` and check the current index

Comment: Yes he didn't mentioned, but he has initialized row to 1 before each iteration. But now your updated answer for row logic looks perfect :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `,` to separate multiple selectors

```
$("input[name='product_id[]'],input[name='product_name[]'],input[name='manufacturer[],input[name='composition[]']").each(function() {               

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is interesting?

note the escaping of the []

```js
const fieldNames = ["product_id[]", "product_name[]", "manufacturer[]", "composition[]"];
const selector = fieldNames.map(item => `input[name='${item}\\\\[\\\\]']`).join(", ")
$rows.each((row) => { 
  $(selector).each(() => {
    let idx = fieldNames.indexOf(this.name)
    row.cells[idx].innerText = $(this).val(); // jquery object or collection?
  })
})
```